# Inicializacion de una lista dinamica ordenada en el constructor de otra classe

Tags: c++, lista

Tengo una clase Jugador con los siguientes atributos:

```
private:
    string a_nom;
    int a_puntuacio;
    int a_ordre;
    // Clase Gorinto es una lista dinámica ordenada 
    Gorinto a_gorinto; 
    //Con un puntero a inicio y una serie de nodos con datos.
```

Y su constructor con parametros es el siguiente;

```
Jugador::Jugador(string nom) {
    a_nom=nom;
    a_puntuacio = 0;
    a_ordre=0;
    a_gorinto = new Gorinto();
}
```

Tengo el problema con la inicialización de `a_gorinto`. No me funciona. ¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

Comment: El miembro a_gorinto es un puntero, luego debería de ser Gorinto *a_gorinto;

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que no te funciona? ¿No compila? ¿Compila pero no se comporta como esperas? ¿Podrías dar más detalles de tu problema?

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta y explicar qué significa "no funciona", incluyendo errores y datos de prueba :)

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Puede resultar confuso cuando vienes de C# o algún otro lenguaje de alto nivel. `new` no tiene el mismo significado. En C++ se instancia llamando al constructor `Clase(p1, p2, ...)`. `new` sirve para asignar memoria y construir un objeto en ella. Luego debes liberarla cuando terminas de usarla.

Answer (score 0):

El miembro `Jugador::a_gorinto` es una instancia de `Gorinto`, si dicha clase provee un constructor por defecto, no necesitas hacer nada en el constructor de `Jugador`:

```
Jugador::Jugador(string nom) {
    a_nom=nom;
    a_puntuacio = 0;
    a_ordre=0;
    // a_gorinto = new Gorinto(); <-- Esto es innecesario
}
```

De hecho puedes reducir aún más el constructor de `Jugador` inicializando sus miembros en el punto de definición:

```
private:
    string a_nom;
    int a_puntuacio = 0;
    int a_ordre = 0;
    Gorinto a_gorinto; 

...
...

Jugador::Jugador(string nom) {
    a_nom=nom;
}
```

Es más, deberías usar la lista de inicialización del constructor, no su cuerpo:

```
Jugador::Jugador(string nom) :
    a_nom{nom}
{
}
```